# Getting double free error when not using copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```
class String
{
private:
    char *s;
    int size;
public:
   String(const char *str = NULL); // constructor
    ~String() { delete [] s;  }// destructor
    //String(const String&); // copy constructor --> i get double free error while running without this
    void print() { cout << s << endl; } // Function to print string
    void change(const char *);  // Function to change
};

String::String(const char *str)
{
    size = strlen(str);
    s = new char[size+1];
    strcpy(s, str);
}

void String::change(const char *str)
{
    delete [] s;
    size = strlen(str);
    s = new char[size+1];
    strcpy(s, str);
}

/*String::String(const String& old_str)
{
    size = old_str.size;
    s = new char[size+1];
    strcpy(s, old_str.s);
}*/

int main()
{
    String str1("Hello");
    String str2 = str1;

    str1.print(); // printed 
    str2.print();

    str2.change("Helloworld");

    str1.print(); // not printed
    str2.print();// printed

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/xJtoTf

I am getting a double free error and the print for `str1` is not being printed the second time (see comments in the code above)...

Is it because when i am not using copy constructor here, instead of default copy constructor being invoked assignment operator is used and both `str2` and `str1` are pointing to same location?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String str2 = str1;` calls the *copy constructor*, not the assignment operator.

As you don't provide the copy constructor, the compiler will supply one automatically. All that will do is copy the member data.

So both `str2` and `str1` will share the same character buffer. Boom!

Comment: Thank you.. I just read the rule of three... Now it make sense.. I was thinking everytime a copy constructor is called a deep copy happens..